# How To Install Eclipse On Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, unix

I Want To Install Eclipse IDE on Linux
By Adding An Icon And Moving It To /opt

**I have Downloaded It But I Want The Right Way To INSTALL**

Comment: This question is a better fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com) but before you ask there keep in mind you've given almost nothing in the way of specifics about what you did or what went wrong.

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Question is neither clear not on topic, plz see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Install Java.**

Don’t have Java installed? Search for and **install OpenJDK Java 7 or 8** via Software Center. Or install oracle java by following this post.

**2. Download Eclipse from its website.**

Check out your OS Type, 32-bit or 64-bit, by going to **

> System Settings -> Details -> Overview,**

then select download Linux 32-bit or 64-bit of Eclipse Installer.

**3. Run the installer wizard.**

Decompress the downloaded archive in your file browser and navigate to the result “**eclipse-installer**” folder, right-click on file eclipse-inst and select Run.Don’t see the “**Run**” option? Go to file browser’s Menu **

> Edit -> Preferences -> Behavior -> check

** “Run executable text files when they are opened”, and finally log out and back in (or run nautilus -q command in terminal).

When the wizard launches, select install item, then installation folder, and finally click INSTALL button.

You may select Advanced Mode from top-right menu to get more options, network proxy settings, 
**4. Create a launcher shortcut.**

Open terminal from Unity Dash, Application Launcher, or via Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut key. When it opens, paste below command and run:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbF1Q.jpg)

**gedit .local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop**

The command creates and opens a launcher file, for current user, with gedit text editor. When it opens, paste below content:

you can see this link [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695382/how-to-install-eclipse-using-its-installer)